# Azure AD authentication using code grant in c#

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, httpclient

Is it possible to achieve authentication using code grant approach without having Microsoft Login UI interim page? Probably like calling HttpPost and HttpGet using c# HttpClient library.

Please be noted that we need to achieve this using code grant approach only and not password grant approach(Graph API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To get an authorization code, you need to take the user to the login page.
The login page may not even show if the user is already signed in.

The Resource Owner Password Credentials grant flow is the only one that can do this kind of approach, but it's use is not recommended and does not work for users who have MFA for instance.

Comment: Thanks Juunas. Will the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant flow authenticate both AD user and on premise server. Actually, we have an AD which synchronizes one on premise server into it. The code grant flow actually authenticates both AD user and on premise user.